# H^{p,q}(CY singularity) vs H^{p,q}(its resolution)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be a 3-dimensional Calabi-Yau singularity over $\mathbb{C}$. Denote the singular point by $0\in X$. Let us further assume that $X$ has a $\mathbb{C}^\times$ action whose only fixed point is $0$. Let $X_0=X\setminus \{0\}$.

Assume there is a crepant resolution $Z\to X$.

I want to compare $H^q(Z,\wedge^p T_Z)$ and $H^q(X_0,\wedge^p T_{X_0})$.

It seems they are isomorphic when $p+q\le 2$. How should I (dis)prove it?

Comment: Is $X$ the cone on a projective variety?

Comment: @Will -- Of course the OP can answer better, but my guess is that the OP wants to allow $X$ to also be a cone over a projective "orbifold", i.e., there may be points in $X_0$ with nontrivial stabilizer group (but presumably all stabilizer groups of points in $X_0$ are finite).  

Comment: Hi Yuji, if I can speculate a bit, I suspect the situation you want is that Z is the total space of a line V-bundle over a Fano orbifold (the easiest example is the total space of the anti-canonical V-bundle over a Fano surface). Then you can write the tangent space to the total space in terms of the tangent space of the base and push-forward everything to the base. My guess is that the result will follow from the Kodaira vanishing theorem for orbifolds (where the 2 arises because the Fano orbifold is at most a surface), but I don't have the time to work it through.

Comment: I want to consider X=C^3, too. This isn't a cone over a projective orbifold, is it? In general I'd like to deal with general toric Calabi-Yau, for example.

Comment: Sure it is. It's the total space of the trivial $C^3$ bundle over a point. I think this should still work for most of the toric CY singularities (the ones in hep-th/0602041, for example). (Also, I should have said canonical bundle above not anti-canonical). The other possibility, I think, is that the resolution of the singularity gives something one dimensional with a $C^2$ bundle over it (like the conifold) -- there might still be vanishing theorem that will work. cont'd.

Comment: Or you might be able to approach things from the non-crepant resolution into a Fano orbifold surface (some power of the resulting line V-bundle is the canonical bundle for quasi-regular SE links). It's been a while and I've forgotten what little I knew of toric world, though. Maybe ask James Sparks?

Comment: Hm. Isn't $\mathbb C^3$ the (usual, simple, trivial) affine cone over $\mathbb P^2$? But it's only crepant resolution is itself for which your statement is obvious, because it is $S_2$.

Comment: By the way, what's your definition of a CY singularity?

Comment: Sorry for my faulty knowledge of math; but I would usually associate $\mathbb{P^2}$ to $\mathbb{C}^3/\mathbb{Z}_3$, because that's the blowdown of the total space of the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{P^2}$ ... 

Comment: @Sándor: my definition is that there is a metric (on $X_0$) whose holonomy is $SU(3)$. I do not know what this translates to in the algebro-geometric language. 

Comment: Hi Sandor, $\mathbb{C}^3$ is an example of what I was talking about above: there are two cones over $\mathbb{P}^2$ that are resolutions of Calabi-Yau cones: the total space of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(3)$. The former, however, is not a crepant "resolution" of $\mathbb{C}^3$ while the latter is a crepant resolution of $\mathbb{C}^3/\mathbb{Z}_3$. I'm not sure if you can approach Yuji's question through the non-crepant resolution, but it seems plausible.